# Finding the solution to $xy'' +2y' +xy=0$ around $x_{0}=0$using the method of Frobenius.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

We know that the solution of this ODE is like:
$$ y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_nx^{n+r}$$

Them derivative $y$ and $y'$.
$$y'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)C_nx^{n+r-1}$$
$$y''=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r-1)(n+r)C_nx^{n+r-2}$$

Replace $y$ , $y'$ and $y''$ in the ODE.
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r-1)(n+r)C_nx^{n+r-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2(n+r)C_nx^{n+r-1} +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_nx^{n+r+1}=0 $$
Now in the first and second summations if $k=n-1$ and in the third summation if $k=n+1$. We have:

$$\sum_{k=-1}^{\infty}(k+r)(k+r+1)C_{k+1}x^{k+r}+\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}2(k+r+1)C_{k+1}x^{k+r} +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{k-1}x^{k+r}=0 $$
Now I separed the $k=-1$ and $k=0$ in the first and second summantions.
$$r(r-1)C_0x^{r-1}+(r+1)(r)C_1x^{r} + 2rC_0x^{r-1} +2(r+1)C_1x^r + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}[(k+r)(k+r+1)C_{k+1}x^{k+r}+2(k+r+1)C_{k+1}x^{k+r}+C_{k-1}x^{k+r}]=0$$
After that I equalized the right side with the left and I have this 2 equation to find $r$:
$$(r^2 +r)C_0=0$$
and
$$(r^2+3r+2)C_{1}=0$$
If you solve the quadratic equations you have:
$$r_1=0$$
$$r_{2,3}=-1$$
$$r_4=-2$$
And that's all that I did please help me.

Comment: From the first one, $r = 0$ or $r = -1$, from the second one, $r = -1$ or $r = -2$. Conclusion?

Comment: Both quadratic equations must be true simultaneously, so you must have $r=-1$ such that they are both true.

Comment: I replace $r=-1$ and find the solution $y$ but I need 2 solutions and I have 2 more $r$, and my doubt is: If I replace $r=0$ and $r=-2$ I think we can find other 2 solutions (Remember I have 1 solution for $r=-1$)

Comment: You could also just get $C_1=0$, if a product is zero, only one of the factors needs to be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$xy'' +2y' +xy=0\qquad ......(1)$$

$~x=0~$ is a regular singular point of equation $(1)$.

So the equation admits of a Frobenius series of the form $$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_n~x^{n+r},\qquad C_0\neq 0 \qquad ..........(2)$$ 
which converges for all $~x~$.

From $(2)$,
$$y'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)C_n~x^{n+r-1};\qquad \qquad y''(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r-1)(n+r)C_n~x^{n+r-2}\qquad .....(3)$$

Substituting $(2)$ and $(3)$ in $(1)$ we get,
$$x~\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r-1)(n+r)C_n~x^{n+r-2}+2~\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)C_n~x^{n+r-1}+x~\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_n~x^{n+r}=0$$
$$\implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)~(n+r+1)~C_n~x^{n+r-1}~+~\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_n~x^{n+r+1}=0\qquad .....(4)$$

Lowest power of $~x~$ in equation $(4)$ is $~{r-1}~$, so coefficient of $~x^{r-1}~=0$ gives the  indicial equation $~r~(r+1)~=0\implies r=0,~-1$

From equation $(4)$ we have the following recursive formula,

$$(n+r+1)~(n+r+2)~C_{n+1}~+~C_{n-1}=0$$
$$\implies C_{n+1}=-\frac{1}{(n+r+1)~(n+r+2)}~C_{n-1}\qquad ........(5)$$

From $(5)$ we have $C_1=C_3=C_5=\cdots =0$

$C_2=-\frac{1}{(r+2)~(r+3)}~C_{0}$

$C_4=-\frac{1}{(r+4)~(r+5)}~C_{2}=\frac{1}{(r+2)~(r+3)~(r+4)~(r+5)}~C_{0}$

$\cdots$

Therefore

$$y(x)=C_0~x^r \left[1-\frac{1}{(r+2)~(r+3)}~x^2+\frac{1}{(r+2)~(r+3)~(r+4)~(r+5)}~x^4-\cdots\right]$$

For $~r=0~$, $$y_1(x)=C_0~ \left[1-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}-\cdots\right]$$
$$\implies y_1(x)=C_0~ \left[1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\cdots\right]$$

Since $~0-(-1)=1,~$ an integer so the other independent solution of equation $(1)$ is  $$y_2(x)=\left[\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\right]_{r=0}$$
$$\implies y_2(x)=y_1(x)~\log x~+~C_0~\left[\frac{5}{36}~x^2+\cdots\right]$$

General solution is $$y(x)=A~y_1(x)~+~B~y_2(x)\qquad \text{where $~A,~B~$are constants.}$$

Comment: Why you dont put $r=-1$ for second solution?

Comment: This is the formula for finding the second solution if the difference between the roots of the indicial equation is an integer. @Kns

Comment: For more details you may follow "Differential Equations"  by Shepley L. Ross

Comment: $\partial y/\partial r |_{r = 0}$ is not a solution. When $r_2 - r_1 \in \mathbb N^+$,
$$\lim_{r \to r_1} \frac \partial {\partial r} ((r - r_1) y(r, x))$$
is a solution, which in this case simply becomes $y(r_1, x)$, there are no solutions with logarithmic factors.

Answer (score 0):

You get the equations ($C_{k}=0$ for $k<0$, by construction)
$$
(k+r)(k+r+1)C_{k}=-C_{k-2}.
$$
The indicial equation for $k=0$ is $r(r+1)=0$. For $r=-1$, the equation for $k=1$ gives also $C_1$ free. All other coefficients are determined by the recursion
$$
C_k=-\frac{C_{k-2}}{k(k-1)}
$$
so that you get a basis solutions in the even indices
$$
y_1(x)=x^{-1}-\frac12x+\frac1{24}x^3-...=\frac{\cos x}{x}
$$
and in the odd indices
$$
y_2(x)=1-\frac16x^2+\frac1{120}x^4+...=\frac{\sin x}x.
$$

The case $r=0$ then just repeats one of these solutions, in that $C_1=0$ and the coefficient recursion
$$
C_k=-\frac{C_{k-2}}{k(k+1)}
$$
gives multiples of
$$
1-\frac16x^2+...=\frac{\sin x}x
$$
that is, of $y_2$.

---

Quick check: Setting $u(x)=xy(x)$ gives $u''(x)=xy''(x)+2y'(x)=-xy=-u$, which is indeed the harmonic oscillator equation.

Comment: Why does r = -1 give two solutions while r = 0 give only one of them? Will smaller value always give 2 solutions when the difference is an integer?

Comment: Yes, in the case of integer difference of the roots that fall not into the logarithmic case, the solution for the smaller root will always also contain the solution for the other root. As the qualifications of the case show, this is not a general situation.

Comment: How to conclude whether the case is logarithmic or not?